# Remove Selected ListViewItem throws Exception

Tags: c#, windows, listview

I get an exception thrown, when I try to remove an item from a list view.

```
 itemListView.Items.Remove(itemListView.SelectedItems[0]);
```

This is my remove Statement at the time, while I already tried different variations.. (SelectedItem, For-Each-Loop, ..).

In my Windows Store application I am showing a list of items. The user now clicks on one of those and presses a button which calls the handler to remove that one selected item (user can only select one item at a time).

Here is the exception that is thrown at the exact line from above:
[image: Exception Message]

Thanks for your help!

Edit: Additional Informations:
The List Items are Objects of some Class.

Debugger not that helpful :(

```
'someAppName.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.DLL'. 
'someAppName.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Csharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Csharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

The Handler that is called consists of only that one line.
SelectedIndex throws the same exception.
No Events attached.

Comment: try using selectedindex?

Comment: We'll need some context - including, but not limited to: What is contained in these ListViewItems? Are there any events attached to them? What does the debugger say about everything right before you step through that line of code? What does your code look like right before the error? Anything you could include would be helpful.

Comment: I updated these informations. But I dont think they'll help :(

Dont bother wasting time right now. Ill try it myself a Little bit longer and will update when theres something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was just being stupid.
I tried to Change a variable that was bound directly instead of changing the source of the binding.